# texlive-20120701-bin install

Tags: installing, texlive

I am new to texlive so pardon me if i miss mentioning more details. I started out with texlive-20120701-bin.tar download and i have extracted them on to a particular file system on my RedHat instance. I have set the path as mentioned in the installation instruction and tried running a test to confirm the install is fine by doing latex sample2e.tex which seems to fail with the below error:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012)
**
Please type the name of your input file.
**sample2e.tex
kpathsea: Running mktexfmt pdftex.fmt
fmtutil: missing command; try fmtutil --help if you need it.
I can't find the format file `pdftex.fmt'!
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: We need more information: Which OS? If you are on Linux: Please use the TeXLive from your distribution instead. See for example 
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu?rq=1

Comment: @MartinSchröder, OP states his Linux system is Red Hat. The TeXlive distribution for Red Hat is quite old, so it is reasonable to look at installing a new, non-official version.

Comment: It looks like you did not install everything. I haven't installed TeXlive that way, so the following are guesses. Does `fmtutil` exist? (`locate(1)` should tell you). Is it on the PATH (`which fmtutil`)?

Comment: If you need new TeXlive, you might want to try Fedora 18. It brings 2012 as standard TeX installation, IIRC.

Comment: Try this following method: http://latex-community.org/component/content/article/66-latex-distributions-texlive/466-texlive-linux

Answer (score 3):

You installed only the binaries without any support files. I recommend one of the two options:
* use any of the rpm package managers to install all of texlive
* use the tug.org original TeX Live
In the current situation you have only bare-bones programs, which is in general not enough for a running system.